# jquery ajax sends an array of objects as an object with index keys. How can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have `var data = {name: "Something", coords: [{lat: 23.23, lng: 123.123}]}`

I send it like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/endpoint",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

When looking at what I get server side, I see this.

```
%{
  "coords" => %{"0" => %{"lat" => "23.23", "lng" => "123.123"}},
  "name" => "Something",
}
```

Why is `[{lat: .., lng: ...}]` getting converted to `{0: {lat: ..., lng: ...}}`? How can I stop this? Is this a jquery thing?

Comment: You can try to stringify your data object and then parse it back on client side. See if that helps.

Comment: because your array of objects is being converted to a hash assuming that's perl or php.  The index of the array appears to be the key of the hash

Answer (score 0):

When you send your data to the https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com bounce-back dummy JSON-server you can see exactly how your data arrives there. Instead of sending the embedded array inside your structure as a whole (=array) its indiviudal elements are sent with their full keys `"coords[0][lat]"` and `"coords[0][lng]"`:

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "coords[0][lat]": "23.23",
  "coords[0][lng]": "123.123",
  "id": 101
}
```

```js
var data = {name: "Something", coords: [{lat: 23.23, lng: 123.123}]}
$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  success: function(response){console.log(response);}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to avoid that behaviour you will have to send the object as a JSON-encoded string and (explicitly!) decode it on the receiving end:

```js
var data = {name: "Something", coords: [{lat: 23.23, lng: 123.123}]}
$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {d: JSON.stringify(data)},
  success: function(response){console.log(JSON.parse(response.d));}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will give you:

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "coords": [
    {
      "lat": 23.23,
      "lng": 123.123
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `JSON.stringify` the data before sending it.

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Also, you need to put `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @PeterR Also, you need to put `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`